# How to install mqtt library in Qt 5.15.2

Tags: c++, linux, qt

> cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/externlabs-rajel052/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib/qtmqtt/src/src.pro ) && make -f Makefile
> make[1]: Entering directory '/home/externlabs-rajel052/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib/qtmqtt/src'
> cd mqtt/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/externlabs-rajel052/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib/qtmqtt/src/mqtt/mqtt.pro ) && make -f Makefile
> make[2]: Entering directory '/home/externlabs-rajel052/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib/qtmqtt/src/mqtt'
> g++ -c -include .pch/Qt5Mqtt -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -std=c++1z -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -Wvla -Wdate-time -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-deprecated-copy -Wno-redundant-move -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-init-list-lifetime -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_FOREACH -DQT_NO_JAVA_STYLE_ITERATORS -DQT_NO_LINKED_LIST -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_BUILD_MQTT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I../../include -I../../include/QtMqtt -I../../include/QtMqtt/5.15.2 -I../../include/QtMqtt/5.15.2/QtMqtt -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.12.8 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.12.8/QtCore -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I.moc -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o .obj/qmqttclient.o qmqttclient.cpp
> In file included from qmqttclient.cpp:31:
> qmqttclient_p.h:49:10: fatal error: private/qobject_p.h: No such file or directory
> 49 | #include <private/qobject_p.h>
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
> make[2]: *** [Makefile:619: .obj/qmqttclient.o] Error 1
> make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/externlabs-rajel052/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib/qtmqtt/src/mqtt'
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:47: sub-mqtt-make_first] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/externlabs-rajel052/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib/qtmqtt/src'
> make: *** [Makefile:49: sub-src-make_first] Error 2

Comment: Is `qobject_p.h` findable on any of the paths referneces by either the `-I` or `-isystem` flags? You also seem to be building this inside a Qt 5.15.2 source tree, while your system has Qt 5.12.8. Which one did you want to link to?

Comment: Do you know where "private/qobject_p.h" is located?

Comment: Did you build two versions of Qt from the source?